# Use ImageMagic synchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, imagemagick

Try to use [imagemagick](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemagick)

Need to use imagemagick synchronously.

I.e next code should be performed only after image convertion will be finished (no matter with error or successfully)

I see only the one solution with [deasync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deasync):

```
const ImageMagick = require('imagemagick');
const Deasync = require('deasync');

var finished = false;
ImageMagick.convert(
  [
    source,
    path_to
  ],
  function(err, stdout){
    finished = true;
});

Deasync.loopWhile(function(){return !finished;});

// the next code performed only after image convertion will be done
```

Are there any variants how to work with imagemagick synchronously?

Comment: The nature of node.js is asynchronous, there should be no need to do things synchronously in node.js.

Comment: Why don't you wrap your `ImageMagick.convert` call into a promise and use async/await? Or `promise.then`?

Comment: @TKoL, it is a good idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Node.js is single threaded so you should try to avoid to make functions like this sync. You can probably just execute your code in the callback function.

```
const ImageMagick = require('imagemagick');

ImageMagick.convert(
  [
    source,
    path_to
  ],
  function(err, stdout){
    // the next code performed only after image convertion will be done
});
```

Or you can use Promise and await, but then your whole function will be async

```
const ImageMagic = require('imagemagick');

function convertImage(source, path_to){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ImageMagick.convert(
            [
                source,
                path_to
            ],
            function(err, stdout){
                if(err) {
                    reject(err)
                }
                resolve(stdout);
            });
    })
}

async function doStuff(){
    // start the image convert
    let stdout = await convertImage(source, path_to);
    // now the function will go on when the promise from convert image is resolved
    // the next code performed only after image convertion will be done
}
```

Comment: I thought about it, but in my case it is impossible to enter the next code into callback.

Comment: Can you edit you question with some more details why you cant do it so may find a solution then.

Comment: BraveButter, it will be easier to say here - I transfer my project from PHP to Reactjs with Express.  I have an image (photos) loader which create a lot of images with different sizes. This function called consistently many times in one API request. So I think it will be cumbersome to call next function from previous.

Comment: Added a code sample for the async await approch @TKoL mentioned